# AddressSanitizer clang direct leak address

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, clang, sanitizer

How can I find out the address of direct leak in clang address sanitizer. For example, if it returns

```
Direct leak of 32 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:                                                                                                                                                           
    #0 0x40926f in operator new(unsigned long) (/home/sg/Downloads/main+0x40926f)                                                                                                                                  
    #1 0x428f31 in AvlTree::insert(AvlTree::Node*, int) /home/sg/Downloads/main.cpp:161:16                                                                                                                         
    #2 0x428fbf in AvlTree::insert(AvlTree::Node*, int) /home/sg/Downloads/main.cpp:170:23                                                                                                                         
    #3 0x428e4d in AvlTree::Insert(int) /home/sg/Downloads/main.cpp:152:16                                                                                                                                         
    #4 0x4293f0 in main /home/sg/Downloads/main.cpp:302:13                                                                                                                                                         
    #5 0x7f67dd56b82f in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-bfm8X4/glibc-2.23/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:291                                                                                                              

Direct leak of 32 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:                                                                                                                                                           
    #0 0x40926f in operator new(unsigned long) (/home/sg/Downloads/main+0x40926f)                                                                                                                                  
    #1 0x428f31 in AvlTree::insert(AvlTree::Node*, int) /home/sg/Downloads/main.cpp:161:16                                                                                                                         
    #2 0x428f9e in AvlTree::insert(AvlTree::Node*, int) /home/sg/Downloads/main.cpp:166:22                                                                                                                         
    #3 0x428f9e in AvlTree::insert(AvlTree::Node*, int) /home/sg/Downloads/main.cpp:166:22                                                                                                                         
    #4 0x428e4d in AvlTree::Insert(int) /home/sg/Downloads/main.cpp:152:16                                                                                                                                         
    #5 0x4293f0 in main /home/sg/Downloads/main.cpp:302:13                                                                                                                                                         
    #6 0x7f67dd56b82f in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-bfm8X4/glibc-2.23/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:291                                                                                                              

SUMMARY: LeakSanitizer: 64 byte(s) leaked in 2 allocation(s).
```

How could I know the address of those leaks?

Comment: What good do you think you can achieve by knowing the address? It's unlikely to help you fix the leak.

Comment: @StoryTeller, if I'm not mistaken, if it's not freed, I can find out what was written in that address.

Comment: That address is only valid through the run the sanitizer examines. It's very likely not going to be the same address for that element at the next run.

Comment: I recommend you produce a short test case. Such that only that **last** insert results in a leak (just run sanitizer after you add an insert and recompile). Then step into the insert operation, and see what happens.

Comment: @StoryTeller, of course, but when I run the program in lldb, AddressSanitizer reports breakpoint hit, so I can look, what is at that address.